# How to run near-js-api tests against a localnet with multiple contracts

Tags: nearprotocol

I have set up node:

```js
nearup run localnet --binary-path ~/code/nearcore/target/release
```

I am trying to run a jest test case:

```js
beforeAll(async function () {
  // NOTE: nearlib and nearConfig are made available by near-cli/test_environment
  const near = await nearlib.connect(nearConfig)
})
```

However there is obvious step missing how to create test accounts on your local node. This is the error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Can not sign transactions for account test.near, no matching key pair found in Signer.

      at node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:83:23
      at Object.exponentialBackoff [as default] (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/exponential-backoff.js:7:24)
      at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:80:24)
      at Account.createAndDeployContract (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:176:9)
      at LocalTestEnvironment.setup (node_modules/near-cli/test_environment.js:39:9)
```

Also looks like `near-js-api` is hardcoded to deploy only one contract. I need to test multiple contracts. How can I deploy multiple contracts? From near-js-api `test_environment.js`

```js
class LocalTestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
    }

    async setup() {
        this.global.nearlib = require('near-api-js');
        this.global.nearAPI = require('near-api-js');
        this.global.window = {};
        let config = require('./get-config')();
        this.global.testSettings = this.global.nearConfig = config;
        const now = Date.now();
        // create random number with at least 7 digits
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999999 - 1000000) + 1000000);
        config = Object.assign(config, {
            contractName: 'test-account-' + now + '-' + randomNumber,
            accountId: 'test-account-' + now + '-' + randomNumber
        });
        const keyStore = new nearAPI.keyStores.UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(PROJECT_KEY_DIR);
        config.deps = Object.assign(config.deps || {}, {
            storage:  this.createFakeStorage(),
            keyStore,
        });
        const near = await nearAPI.connect(config);

        const masterAccount = await near.account(testAccountName);
        const randomKey = await nearAPI.KeyPair.fromRandom('ed25519');
        const data = [...fs.readFileSync('./out/main.wasm')];
        await config.deps.keyStore.setKey(config.networkId, config.contractName, randomKey);
        await masterAccount.createAndDeployContract(config.contractName, randomKey.getPublicKey(), data, INITIAL_BALANCE);

        await super.setup();
    }
```

near-js-sdk itself is deploying against mysterious shared-test

```
    case 'ci':
        return {
            networkId: 'shared-test',
            nodeUrl: 'https://rpc.ci-testnet.near.org',
            masterAccount: 'test.near',
        };
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can I deploy multiple contracts?

You can use `masterAccount.createAndDeployContract` same as `test_environment.js`. There is nothing special there except some common init - you can instead create whatever accounts / contracts are needed for your tests directly.

> near-js-sdk itself is deploying against mysterious shared-test

This is shared network which can be used to run integration tests. Unless you want to keep your dev work private – it is recommended way to run tests (as hits most realistic environment currently available for testing).

> However there is obvious step missing how to create test accounts on your local node.

If you created project using `create-near-app` you likely have corresponding `test.near` keys in `neardev/` project folder already. That's why above mysterious environment generally works out of box.

For your local environment you need to create `test.near` yourself:

```
NODE_ENV=local near create-account test.near --masterAccount some-existing-account
```

After that you can copy keys to local format (or just reconfigure `UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore` to use `~/.near-credentials` path):

```
cp ~/.near-credentials/local/test.near.json project/dir/neardev/local/test.near.json
```